# Dagger.android - should every activity get its own subcomponent

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I am referring to [dagger.android](https://google.github.io/dagger//android.html) packages.  I am trying to see if its feasable to actually use this or if the complexity is just too much for a enterprise application.  If you look at step # 2 : it reads:

> Start off by writing a @Subcomponent that implements AndroidInjector, with a @Subcomponent.Builder that extends AndroidInjector.Builder:

so that mean that for every new Activity that I have I should create another SubComponent ? and likewise for every Fragment ?

Actually i started looking into this approached based on [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476006/dagger-and-mvp-should-presenter-use-dagger-for-injection)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. but i fail to see how the questions are similar. the docs in dagger.android are stating that its mandatory for each activity to have its own subcomponent it seems. i wanted verification on this. my question relates to dagger.android only, not dagger2 in general.

Comment: Ok I see how it is different now

Comment: AFAIK, the answer is yes (but I have nothing more than experience to back this up). Did you dig into it more?

Comment: no, it was getting so complex. i stayed with dagger2.